# Handling rotation?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
     setContentView(R.layout.login);
 }
 else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                setContentView(R.layout.login);
 }
```

I have 2 login.xml (one in layout folder, the other one is in layout-land folder). When first time I run the program it working fine (for example in PORTRAIT mode) and when I rotate the device it doesn't call LANDSCAPE mode. it just rotate same login.xml.
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep one login.xml in res/layout and another one in res/layout-land and remove the if else condition just put :

```
   setContentView(R.layout.login)
```

when the orientation of the device changes, Android will automatically load the appropriate XML file..
It works in my case ...

Answer (score 1):

move your login.xml file to "layout-port" folder which is in the "layout" folder
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

if you have two xml files with the same name in layout and layout-land , the activity will know to get the appropriate layout ,it's no need for you to have a test of orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep both files in different folders `res/layout` and another one in `res/layout-land` and just write:

```
setContentView(R.layout.login)
```

or, if is still not working, then you can use the same code with diff layout path

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
     setContentView(R.layout.login);
 }
 else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                setContentView(R.layout-land.login);
 }
```